# (bluebird .tap) Can't return data, do wrong

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, bluebird

I do:

```js
 return new bluebird((resolve) => {

  bluebird.resolve()
  .tap(saveExcelFiles)
  .tap(...)
  .tap(() => {
      return getZip().then((rows) => {
        resolve(rows) // this outer bluebird helps me
        return rows;
      });
    })
  ;
  
});
```

How to return all data(for each tap) or just last tap in one bluebird wrap.

P.S. I need sequencing (one by one, tap by tap)

Comment: @alexmac, could you improve some example pls?

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.tap` explicitly means "ignore the return value", if you need the return value - use the standard `.then`:

```
.then(() => {
  return getZip().then((rows) => {
    // Nothing outer.
    return rows;
  });
});
```

Or more compactly:

```
.then(getZip); // that's it!
```

Also, you should `return` the promise chain instead of [explicit construction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it):

```
return saveExcelFiles().tap(...).then(getZip);
```

Should suffice for the entire body of your function.